# How can I allow documents within a bucket to access other documents in the same bucket without allow public access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to use AWS S3 to get around the CORS policy with an html document. I am running into an issue where my HTML document can't reference the JavaScript and CSS files in the same bucket. The only way I was able to allow this so far was to allow public access to everyone using this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For obvious reasons, I would like to allow my documents to reference one another while keeping my bucket/website private. Is there a way to do this? The policy above is from Amazon's help page, so I assume it would be through changing the principal in the policy. However, I am not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: The HTML document is not accessing the other documents at all. The user's browser is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript and CSS will be downloaded by the browser so they must be publicly accessible.

If you want to have a private bucket, then you can create a CloudFront distribution to serve the content (it will cost you more money.)

Answer (score 1):

If You would like to serve the website publicly accessible, but you would like to have your bucket private, you need to setup origin access identity via cloud front distribution, which means you only allow cloudfront to access the bucket.

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Id":"PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "Sid":" Grant a CloudFront Origin Identity access to support private content",
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Principal":{"CanonicalUser":"CloudFront Origin Identity Canonical User ID"},
       "Action":"s3:GetObject",
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3::: mybucketname/*"
     }
   ]
}
```

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: You can serve a website from a private bucket by using CloudFront